# Extracting certain characters from the last line of text file using a .bat file

Tags: parsing, batch-file, text-extraction

What I'm trying to accomplish here is to pull data from the last line of this file ftp://ftp.nhc.noaa.gov/atcf/tcweb/invest_al902012.invest. I've managed to download it and save it as a script.txt file through a .bat file. I now want to extract the latitude(13.5N) and longitude(27.2W) as well as pressure(1009) from the last line of the file and write it to a new file.I then used this code to do part of what I want:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%x in (script.txt) do (
    set "previous=!last!"
    set "last=%%x"
) 
echo !previous!>> "test3.txt"
for /f "delims=*" %%x in (test3.txt) do (
set line=%%x
set chars=!line:~35,-125!
echo !chars!>> "test.txt"
)
```

I'm illiterate when it comes to batch coding. This is probably extremely inefficient and only extracts the latitude part of the code I want. The file will always contain the same amount of characters in the last line so I'm thinking I'm just not grasping the concept of the !line part of the code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is comma delimited, so it is probably easier to let FOR /F parse the line into tokens and keep just the ones you want.

This really simple solution parses and sets values for each line, but only the last line is remembered. The performance should be fine as long as the file never becomes huge.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=7,8,10 delims=," %%A in (script.txt) do (
  set lat=%%A
  set long=%%B
  set pres=%%C
)
echo latitude=%lat%, longitude=%long%, pressure=%pres%
```

If you want to strip off the spaces, then you could simply use search and replace.

```
echo latitude=%lat: =%, longitude=%long: =%, pressure=%pres: =%
```

I do not simply include space as a delimiter in the FOR /F statement because that can throw off the token counting when a value is sometimes blank and sometimes not.